# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to boot after shutdown and requires "Repair-boot".After repair, it will boot fine, but will *probably* require it at next power up

Tags: boot

I've a new Ubuntu installation that's causing me grief.
The majority of the time, especially if I just reboot it boots fine. However (for the last three days) when I powered down for the night, and came in the next morning, the system would get past POST, and then get stuck on a blank screen.

I've tried all manner of key presses to bring up a terminal or something. There's no debug or anything I can seem to access on this blank screen, so I've no idea what's actually going wrong.

I can use live boot and then boot repair to fix the issue and it will reboot fine. However I just tried this again this morning and then powered off the machine for a few minutes. When I went to power back on I was at the black screen again. I've run repair boot aagain and the output link that is given is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qTP9wpB7Jt/

This is a UEFI system (CSM turned off). There is a RAID, but the boot is on its own SSD not connected to the RAID. The system is an AMD APU. The motherboard is an ASRock A320M.

I'm really frustrated with this now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not know RAID, but have this in my notes: dmraid was replaced by mdadm for handling FakeRAID in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. Did not know that dmraid may interfere as Boot-Repair posts. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI, but Ubuntu has worked with MBR. Grub recently updated, not sure then if gpt/MBR is part of issue or not. You also have BIOS boot loaders in MBR of every drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only wants to install UEFI boot to first drive. See this bug and work arounds:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  or move SSD to lower SATA port so sda

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the response!

dmraid isn't installed. It seems to be something to do with the live boot repair image. Also, the raid isn't used for booting.
I have updated and have the latest grub.

"You also have BIOS boot loaders in MBR of every drive" 
I didn't do any of this manually, it's an Ubuntu install that was repaired with boot-repair. I'm not sure what your comment even means (noob, sorry).
I can't move the SSD as it's an M.2 drive unfortunately.

Comment: My M.2 SATA drive was sda, so I had no issues with my desktop. But it replaces SATA0 port, I believe, so had to use higher ports for sdb. Your Windows BIOS boot loaders then must be from old Windows installs on sda & sdb as Boot-Repair cannot install that. If you attempted a BIOS repair of sdc, Boot-Repair could have installed a BIOS grub to sdc, or an old install. You show mount of ESP in fstab, so currently UEFI install.  How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs or repairs. If you partition in advance and want UEFI, you should change to gpt first.